# Hiding an UIView takes a long time

Tags: objective-c, xcode9.2, ios11.2

Good day ...!

I want to simply hide an UIView (called "secondView") by pressing a button inside it.
The problem I'm running into is that when I press the button, it takes a long time (about 20 seconds) to perform the method and hide its superview, and I just see this problem on **iphone simulators running on iOS 11.2**. I've tested on iOS 9.0 iphone simulator and iphone 5 iOS 10.3 real device. Unfortunately I don't have any real device with iOS 11.2 installed on to test.

this is the method I use to hide the UIView:

```
-(IBAction)hideSecondView:(id)sender{
    secondView.hidden = YES;
}
```

According to the topic [Showing hidden view really slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38057233/showing-hidden-view-really-slow) and the answer provided by @Duncan C, I changed my code the following:

```
-(IBAction)hideSecondView:(id)sender{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        secondView.hidden = YES;
    });
}
```

But the problem is still there :(

Any help would be appreciated.

**Update1:**

As [the snippet enhanced by @drct](https://gist.github.com/drct/bb4b1f93f8790cca9c9f), I checked to see if there was any UIKit access on threads other than main. But no catching!

I have a simple test project and the [Main thread checker](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/code_diagnostics/main_thread_checker?language=objc) shows that no other tread is spawned by application. I paused execution right along the hiding delay time of secondView.

Comment: you want only hide data or reclick you want that view back?

Comment: You can try by setting alpha of your view to 0. setting alpha to 0 give same result as hide and make it invisible.

Comment: @RealmOfFire I want the view back.

Comment: than sethidden:NO

Comment: @Ajaysaini Yes it does, but i have another objects in that view like buttons and etc, and in that case i should disable all of them which gets a lot of code!

Comment: @RealmOfFire setHidden:NO works fine, the problem appears whenever i try to hide the view **by a button inside it**!

Answer (score 0):

@Duncan C wrote a nice answer describing your issue.

> You may have other code that's trying to do UIKit calls from a background thread when you're not aware of it.

Can you check that you have no other UIKit calls?

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
Considering my level of knowledge I did the check, more explanation is added in update. Is there another check to do?